# Assigning multiple materials to multiple obj files in Maya

Tags: import, maya, assign

I'm looking for a script in Phyton or Mel where is can assign different materials to an OBJ imported file from Rhino and the same materials to the next OBJ file also imported from Rhino.

Is that possible?

Here's what I have tried:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds 
import glob 

def importFile(i): 
     cmds.file(i, i=True, groupReference=True, groupName="myobj") 

def materialFile(): 
   cmds.select("myobj") 
   myMaterial = "blinn2" 
   cmds.sets( e=True, forceElement= myMaterial + 'SG' )
```

The obj files parts come in groups and I need to assign a different material to each group. i.e: group 5, group 6, group7

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already ? .. or are you asking us to write it ? ;)

Comment: @theodox I have this code in Phyton, but it only works with the blinn shader. I can't assign a shader from a renderer or even lambert.

'code' import maya.cmds as cmds
import glob

def importFile(i):
    cmds.file(i, i=True, groupReference=True, groupName="myobj")
def materialFile():
    cmds.select("myobj")
    myMaterial = "blinn2"
    cmds.sets( e=True, forceElement= myMaterial + 'SG' )'code'

The obj files parts come in groups and I need to assign a different material to each group. i.e: group 5, group 6, group7

Comment: OBJ files typically come with an associated MTL file, do you have those?

Comment: @theodox no because the idea is to assign the materials in maya. At the moment I'm using Maxwell render, so I need to apply its materials

Comment: @achayan I tried already but the code only applies one material and I need to apply two or three materials in the obj file

Comment: @jpits If you want to assign a material only on some part of an object, you need to have the list of faces on which the material will be applied.

Comment: @UKDP I have in the outliner my obj like this: group, and inside the group I have the parts model7_:object_1 and model7_:Round.

How can I add them to the script?

Comment: @UKDP I'm using Maxwell Render materials. The name of the shader is Gold2 and glass2. I need to assign Gold2 to model7_:object_1 and glass2 to model7_:Round  

Also, I need to know if Maxwell current render is set

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have have the list of objects and corresponding (existing?) shaders, there is no particular difficulty.
Here is the code.

```
from maya import cmds

# Here we have the list of all our shaders with the
# polygon shapes or polygon faces on which they are assigned
objectsShaders = {'blinn3': ['pCube4.f[1:3]', 'pCube4.f[5]', 'pCubeShape2'],
                  'blinn4': ['pCube4.f[0]', 'pCube4.f[4]', 'pCubeShape3'],
                  'blinn5': ['pSphereShape1']}

# Loop through the dictionary
for shader, allObjs in objectsShaders.items():

    # First we retrieve all the shading engine
    # connected to the current shader
    # (We will assume we only have one)
    shaderConnections = cmds.listConnections (shader)

    sahdingEngine = ''
    for connection in shaderConnections:
        if cmds.objectType (connection) == 'shadingEngine':
            sahdingEngine = connection
            break

    # For each object of the list,
    # we assign the shader to it
    for obj in allObjs:

        cmds.sets (obj, edit = True, forceElement = sahdingEngine)

# End statement
print 'All the shaders were successfully re-assigned to their coresponding objects.'
```

When assigning a shader in Maya we actually connect the object shape (or faces) to the shadingEngine, not the shader itself. 
Another think is that you don't add the object to the set, it's more like you're assigning the set to the object. That's why it is:

```
cmds.sets (obj, edit = True, forceElement = sahdingEngine)
```

And not (like other Maya commands):

```
cmds.sets (sahdingEngine, edit = True, forceElement = obj)
```

**EDIT**
I used blinn for the example but the principle is the same for all shaders (I think).

Comment: @ UKDP Thanks for help. How can I now mix it with the code I have? The general flow of this code is:

So I need to know where to add your code. Here is the rest of the code I have with the one at the beginning of this question:

`def renderFile(i):
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix", i, type="string")
    cmds.render(batch=True)`

`def deleteFile():
    cmds.select("myobj")
    cmds.delete()`

`myglob = glob.glob("/Path/to/my/obj/*.obj")`

`for i in myglob:
    importFile(i)
    moveFile()
    materialFile()
    renderFile(i)
    deleteFile()`

Comment: @jpits Unfortunately there are too many parameters I don't know about your script. I suppose it would be somewhere between `materialFile()` and `renderFile(i)` but I can't really tell...
If you don't know how to make this work you should ask someone who knows the project and how to properly implement it.

Comment: Ok. I have another question. The code is perfectly working with my first obj file. But when Import my second obj, it gives me an error `No object matches name: ` because it has less parts than the first imported obj. is there any code ignore the error and finish the operation?

Comment: @jpits `No object matches name` mean that your obj does not exists. Maybe it hasn't been properly imported in the scene or - if you hard coded the object name in the script - there is some orthographic error or something.

Comment: I have two obj files which are imported as groups. The first group is composed by four polyshapes: metal_01, metal_02, metal_03, metal_04. The second group is composed only by three polyshapes: metal_01, metal_02, metal_03. I replaced the names in your script with the same names of the obj parts:
`objectsShaders = {'blinn3': ['metal_01',  'metal_01_Shape']` same until metal_04.
Because the second obj doesn't have metal_04 it gives me an error and doesn't apply the rest of the materials. I need to make ignore this error and finish the task.

Comment: If the shader is assigned to the whole object, just provide the shapes, **not the transforms**. For example, with the objects: metal_01, metal_02, metal_03, your dictionary will look like `objectsShaders = {'material': [ 'metal_01_Shape',  'metal_02_Shape',  'metal_03_Shape']`

Comment: Thanks. I solved it in some way by typing * next to the element, i.e: metal* or metal_01_shape*. But this is in case I want all metals with the same color. Now I need to make it to identify the object If I want a different color to  a specific piece

Comment: I can't help you further, everything you need is in the code. If it's a naming problem it's inherent to your specific case...